# Returning multiple values with Fuse.js

Tags: javascript, json, fuse.js

I'm working with Fuse.js to perform a fuzzy search on a JSON structure. Each object in my JSON contains four variables: `video-title`, `video-tags`, `video-desc` and `video-url`.

I can return all four of these properties, or return the ID property. However, I'd like to return three of the properties, those being the title, description and URL.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you found the object from your search you want to return. Why don't you just return the whole object and access the properties you need?
If you don't want to do this just return a new object

```
function returnObj(fuzzysearch){
   return { video-title: fuzzysearch.video-title, video-url: fuzzysearch.video-url, video-desc: fuzzysearch.video-desc };
}
```